# Proving: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[\sin\left( \frac{1}{n} \right ) - \ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right )]$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to figure out how to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[\sin\left( \frac{1}{n}  \right ) - \ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right )]$ converages.

From a similar [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685496/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-ln1-frac1n) I learn that I could use the integral test but I can't seem to figure out how to use it on $\sin\left( \frac{1}{n}  \right )$. It quite difficult to calculate $\int_{x=0}^{\infty}(\sin\left( \frac{1}{x} \right ) - \ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right ))dx$. Wolfram says that I can use the comparison test, but how?

Answer (score 2):

$\sin(1/n) = 1/n + O(1/n^2)$ and $\ln(1+1/n) = 1/n + O(1/n^2)$, so $\sin(1/n) - \ln(1+1/n) = O(1/n^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sin\frac{1}{n}\le \frac{1}{n}$; use the first two terms of the Maclaurin series for $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Taylor Series for both. They would suggest that

$$\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) < \frac{1}{n} \hspace{24 pt} \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) > \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n^2}$$

by the Taylor remainder theorem. Then we have

$$\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) < \frac{1}{n} - \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n^2}\right) = \frac{1}{2n^2}$$

From there we are done by comparison test.

Comment: You also need inequalities in the other direction.

Comment: @RobertIsrael No we don't. This series is always positive for $n\geq 1$

Comment: Well then, that's an inequality in the other direction.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Haha fair enough!